# Is the iPhone Simulator UDID unique for each installed instance?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, udid

i.e. does this call:

```
NSString *udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
```

return always the same UDID when it is executed on the iPhone Simulator on any mac computer or not?

Currently the iPhone Simulator on my computer returns "2BA99337-3AE2-5234-93DA-193703B876F8".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My UDID is reporting as 03B41D62-FB69-5B6D-A95E-473842F4DFE3 from the iPhone Simulator, so it looks like you're correct.

Answer (score 45):

The UDID of the simulator is actually the same as the UDID of your Mac. You can easily verify this by looking at the System Profiler utility (where it is called the Hardware UUID).

On iPhones, iPads and iPod Touches, it is 40 lowercase hex digits, probably a SHA1 hash of some hardware identifier.

Comment: When I run the simulator under Xcode (developer tools->ios simulator) each virtual device (Hardware->device->manage) I click from the list  shows me a different identifier, and none are similar to my mac UUID.

Comment: They probably changed the Xcode 4 behavior in line with iOS 7 changes for UDID. In iOS 7, the UDID is now "ffffffff" followed by the identifierForVendor stripped of its hyphens.

Answer (score 15):

Xcode has this data for you:

1. Xcode 5: Open Organizer
2. Click My Mac
3. Look at the Identifier for the machine there.

   -OR-
4. Xcode 6: Open Devices (CMD+SHIFT+2 -OR- Window -> Devices)
5. Click the simulator you're running
6. Look at the Identifier for the simulator there

Comment: I can't find "my mac" anywhere.  Did you mean step 1 to say "open devices" instead?

Comment: @MattParkins I've updated my answer to respect your observation that I only accounted for Xcode 5 at that time. I've now added Xcode 6 as well.

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal and type in `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` - the output under **Hardware UUID** is the ID used for all instances of iOS simulator running on that specific computer.

Comment: This is not correct in my case.  
Hardware UUID: B8EBD816-974E-57F2-BF3C-F60385B3EFE1,  
Simulator's Identifier in Xcode: 66742464-8B19-4D25-B132-F5DE75CB296C,  
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]: CC6E8A6F-40CD-40DA-A7DB-C5BF19527467,

macOS: 10.11.6,  
Xcode: 8.1 (8B62),  
Simulator: iPad Air (iOS 9.3)