# View Apple KeyChain Contents

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite, keychain

I successfully store and load a password field into my Apple KeyChain. 
I know that because I tested it and it seems working with the print statement.

---

I wonder if there is a way to view it just like UserDefault.

This is the path of the database `keychain-2-debug.db`

`/Users/kyo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E3A9927-DBDA-486F-9DAE-8D75D0008B92/data/Library/Keychains/keychain-2-debug.db`

[image]

When I open that I see one table `genp`

[image]

Someone please shed some light on this

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862997/ios-simulator-view-content-of-keychain

Comment: what are you trying to view exactly ?

Comment: I'm trying to view the all the key/value of my keychain.

Comment: I do not think it is possible on a not jail broken device, otherwise you might be qualifying for apple bounty for finding security hole. Please refer to Apple security document which is putting some light how things are protected